# Service background music does not turn off

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

In my app there is a background music, for what I have a service. It works fine, but it "*keeps playing*" when either I close the app or turn off the screen.
Should I change something in `onPause` or `onStop`?

**My code:**

```
public class MyService extends Service {


private final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.id);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100, 100);




}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    return 1;
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TO DO
}

public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TO DO Auto-generated method
    return null;
}


protected void onStop() {
    player.pause();
}

public void onPause() {
    player.pause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {

}

}
```

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/UsingServicetoplaymediafile.htm

Answer (score 0):

As screen turns off your activity becomes invisible which triggers **onPause** followed by **onStop**

Screen on, on the other hand, triggers **onStart** followed by **onResume**.

when ever you want to stop service use

`stopService(new Intent(ActivityName.this, ServiceClassName.class));`

Answer (score 0):

Probably copies of the player are created somehow. Try to make MediaPlayer variable static and then try to deallocate it after pausing onPause(). Anyway it is weird, that you are creating MediaPlayer instance in service.